# how to rename log status from unknown to skip in extent report

Tags: testng, report, extentreports, extent

If skipped test cases are shown as unknown in extent test report then how to rename logstatus.unknown to logstatus.skip

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works fro me

@AfterMethod 
    public void testStatus()
    { 
        if (test.getRunStatus().equals(LogStatus.UNKNOWN))
        { 
            test.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "This test method is skipped");
        }
    }